# Cannot set specific param from $_GET

Tags: php, nginx, qr-code, php-5.3

*Note - I am unsure whether this a lib problem or a problem with my code - please advise on this*

I have used [this lib](https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode) to create a parameterised PHP page so that we can generate QR codes from the params in the url:

```
include( '/qrlib/qrlib.php' );

if (isset($_GET['fg'])&&!empty($_GET['fg'])) {
    $fore_color = $_GET['fg'];
} else {
    $fore_color = 0x000000;
}

if (isset($_GET['bg'])&&!empty($_GET['bg'])) {
    $back_color = $_GET['bg'];
} else {
    $back_color = 0xFFFFFF;
}

QRcode::png($_GET['url'], false, $_GET['err'], $_GET['size'], $_GET['pixel'], false, $back_color, $fore_color);
```

This works perfectly for `url`, `err`, `size` and `pixel` but as soon as I try and set the colours from the URL - the respective colour change (fg or bg) just defaults to black.

However, if the variables `$fore_color` or `$back_color` are set explicitly (not through the URL and use the `else` statement then they work. (I should note that if you look at the above they will default to black FG and white BG if the param isn't set).

I have echo'd out the `$fore_color` and `$back_color` to check the values are being passed correctly and they are showing up exactly as expected - this behaviour occurs when one or both of the color params are populated in the URL.

I set up a few examples here:

http://rd.exitex.com/qr.php?url=test&size=40&pixel=1&err=L&bg=0xFFFFFF&fg=0x000000

http://rd.exitex.com/qr.php?url=test&size=40&pixel=1&err=L&bg=0xFFFFFF

http://rd.exitex.com/qr.php?url=test&size=40&pixel=1&err=L&fg=0x000000

http://rd.exitex.com/qr.php?url=test&size=40&pixel=1&err=L

Any advice as to this strange behaviour please advise. (Server running on NginX 1.3.8 with PHP-FPM 5.3.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the argument in Decimal, not Hexadecimal.

So, for example, for a light gray BG and green FG:
http://rd.exitex.com/qr.php?url=test&size=40&pixel=1&err=L&bg=15724527&fg=2068254

In your code, you're getting the parameter as Integer, not Hexadecimal.

Therefore, this is not valid:
0x20921F
This is valid instead:
2134559

Or you need to add the PHP code to convert Hex to Dec.
You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the lib you are using accepts ints and the value you are getting from the $_GET would be a string, try:

```
if (isset($_GET['fg'])&&!empty($_GET['fg'])) {
    $fore_color = settype($_GET['fg'], "integer"); 
} else {
    $fore_color = 0x000000;
}

if (isset($_GET['bg'])&&!empty($_GET['bg'])) {
    $back_color = settype($_GET['bg'], "integer");
} else {
    $back_color = 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: No dice i'm afraid - same symptoms (review above URLs with your changes in place). Myles

Comment: does the lib let you set the bg and fg colour? looking at it, it does not seem to be the case... https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/blob/master/qrimage.php  line 66 onwards

Comment: According to the README it does? https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode/blob/master/README